# Why does the direction of reading code by the compiler/computer change for different cases? (C language)

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Why is it that the computer/compiler "reads" 
 `a=b+a` 
from right to left but not 
 `float b=a+1.2, a=1.0`? 
Both lines of code being completely unrelated.

If the compiler does read from right to left then this:
`float a=1.0, b=a+1.2` should give an error because "a" hasn't been declared yet, right?

Is  `float a=1.0, b=a+1.2` logically correct or  `float b=a+1.2, a=1.0`?

Background: 
I am just starting out C programming, and this is my 3rd program after hello world. So please keep that in mind while answering.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler does not 'read' in any particular direction -- the scope of a variable name starts at the declarator for the variable and extends to the end of the block containing the declaration (or the file if at global scope).  So it includes both the initializer of the declarator and any subsequent declarators in the same declaration, and any subsequent declarations.

Comment: Woah woah woah. A lot of technical terms have been used there. Please explain in kind of layman terms.

Comment: You can't understand C without understanding the terms used to define the language.  These are basic terms defined in any decent introduction to C book.

Comment: @GuyEternal By 'scope' it means that, 'the variable' (`a` in this case) is created at the same time as `b` and both are created prior to initialization takes place. Upon initalization however, it (should) go from left to right, meaning that, at the time of initializing `b`, `a` is uninitialized and therefor contains garbage values. Your compiler should at least give you a warning to that effect.